# Upgrade version of python and pandas on Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I need to use python 3.9.14 and pandas 1.4.2 on Google Colab because of the .npz files I need to work with.
I have successfully installed both using bash commands on the notebook, but it is not effective on the actual version I can use on the notebook itself. Here is some code and output to make it clearer.

Python:

*bash command*

```
!python --version
Python 3.9.14
```

*notebook*

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.7.14 (default, Sep  8 2022, 00:06:44) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
```

---

Pandas:

*bash command*

```
!pip list
    Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------------
...
pandas                  1.4.2
...
```

---

*notebook*

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
1.3.5
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem? It seems that I installed the right version on the virtual machine, but I can't use it on the Colab notebook.
I've tried restarting the runtime, but that leads to a loop: it continuously connects and disconnects to the runtime with no way to do anything.
I hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

---

EDIT, SOLVED: I missed a step. After updating the python version, you need to download the notebook, open it with a text editor and change the name of the 'kernelspec'.

```
"kernelspec": {
  "name": "py39",
  "display_name": "Python 3.9"
}
```

Then you upload it to Colab and everything seems to work.

```
import sys
print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)
User Current Version:- 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the desired version of python and pandas as per your requirement on your google colab. Basically, google colab has debian-based linux, so what you do on linux you can do the same in google colab also.

Now as you say you restart runtime, basically you lost all your changes once you restart the kernel and google colab restore to its previous state, each runtime gives you a fresh and new google colab. So if you install the desired version in your google colab don't restart your runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a step. After updating the Python version, you need to download the notebook, open it with a text editor and change the name of the 'kernelspec'.

```
"kernelspec": {
  "name": "py39",
  "display_name": "Python 3.9"
}
```

Then upload it to Google Colab and it will work.

```
import sys
print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)
User Current Version:- 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
```